# How works RedirectIfAuthenticated.php?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, laravel-artisan

I ran `php artisan make:auth` in Laravel 5.6 as it is well known this did generated a `HomeController.php` file.

Inside that:

`public function index(){
    return view('home');
}`

and `Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');` route definition into `web.php`.

But `http://homestead.test/home` URI redirect to `http://homestead.test/login` due `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` middleware. So `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` works as global middleware instead route middleware although is defined in `$routeMiddleware` property in `Kernel.php`.

Why does this happen?

What do I not know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the constructor of the controller that was created it is using the `auth` middleware.

```
$this->middleware('auth');
```

If you look at your `Kernel.php` at `$routeMiddleware`:

```
'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
```

This doesn't involve `RedirectIfAuthenticated` at all. That would redirect any users who are already authenticated away from a route. The `auth` middleware redirects everyone who isn't authenticated to a route, 'login'.